# How do I convert the following shell commands in a chef recipe?

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, chef-recipe

How do I convert the following shell commands in a chef recipe?

**Install**

```
sudo easy_install pygments
sudo echo 'export RAILS_ENV=production' >> ~/.bash_profile
sudo adduser --system --shell /bin/sh --gecos 'git version control' --group --disabled-password --home /home/git git
ssh-keygen -t rsa
sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
sudo chmod 755 /home/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/hooks/post-update

echo "gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri" > ~/.gemrc
rvmsudo gem install passenger
rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

**Creating an Upstart file for nginx**

sudo vim /etc/init/nginx.conf

```
description "Nginx HTTP Server"

start on filesystem
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

exec /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

**Restart the VM**

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

**Verify nginx running**

```
sudo initctl list | grep nginx
```

Comment: You could wrap it in a bash statement:

bash "overall task description" do
  user "root"
  cwd "/tmp"
  code <<-EOH
  easy_install pygments
  echo 'export RAILS_ENV=production' >> /home/username/.bash_profile
  ...
  EOH
end

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not necessarily the perfect way to do this, but it should work (note I haven't tested).

In your metadata for your cookbook, first make sure you have this:

```
depends "python"
```

then your recipe can look like this:

```
pip_package "pygments"

execute "echo 'export RAILS_ENV=production' >> ~/.bash_profile" do
  not_if "grep RAILS_ENV ~/.bash_profile"
end

user "git" do
  system True
end

execute "ssh-keygen -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa"
  user "git"
  not_if "test -f /home/git/.ssh/id_rsa"
end

execute "gitosis-init < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && chmod 755 ~/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/hooks/postupdate"
  #not sure how do check if this has been run, maybe this is right:
  not_if "test -f /home/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/hooks/post-update"
end

gem_package "passenger" do
  action :install
end

#Instead of creating your own upstart service, why not use the stock nginx config.
include_recipe "nginx"

execute "passenger-install-nginx-module" do
  #I'm not familiar with this, so I don't know how to check if it's already been run.
  notifies :restart, "service[nginx]"
end
```

most of this info should be pretty accessible from the chef docs, btw.